# How do I get first three characters from an edittext?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to get the first three characters from an edittext and then turn them onto a string, but I cant find anything about that. Any ideas?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get text from an EditText, or a TextView, Button, etc. (pretty much any View that has text), you call getText(). This returns a CharSequence, which is *almost* a String, but not quite, so to turn it into a String object, call toString() on it. And then to get the first 3 letters, use the substring() method, where the first argument is the index of the character to start, and the second is *one past the last* character you want. So you want the first 3 characters, which are indices 0,1,2, so we must have 3.

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
CharSequence foo = yourEditText.getText();
String bar = foo.toString();
String desiredString = bar.substring(0,3);
```

In addition, you will probably want to make sure that the user has actually put something in the EditText before assuming that there is and getting a NullPointerException when you try to use the string. So i usually use EditTexts in the following way.

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
String foo = yourEditText.getText().toString();
if(foo.length() > 0) { //just checks that there is something. You may want to check that length is greater than or equal to 3
    String bar = foo.substring(0, 3);
    //do what you need with it
}
```

Comment: I can see that this code works, but the person who is asking may not be as experienced.  Please provide a bit of explanation as to **why** this code works.

Comment: You're right, I changed my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String mString = mEditText.getText().toString().substring(0,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText tEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String text = tEdit.getText().toString();
System.out.println(text.substring(0,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

`mEditText.getText().toString().substring(0,3);`